# Very slow queries in Django view for model with a lot of nested relationships

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

We have a dynamic endpoint that has a huge amount of nested aggregation before fetching all of the records. We've tried indexing the keys, but it didn't seem to make a difference on the speed. We looked at a few different methods of caching things, but because of the scale of the data, it's changing very frequently at a low level. Are there any other options or suggestions that we can try to do to optimize the aggregation of the records?

For reference, we have a `Job` model with a bunch of data about that job. There are a few 1-to-many relationships between `Job` and some other models such as `JobTask`. There is also some data we need that has a 1-to-many relationship with `JobTask`. This means that there is a lot of essentially nested data we need for each job.

As the database has grown, this query is getting noticeably slower for the users and we are trying to see if there is anything we can do to optimize it. We tried using the `Prefetch()` class in all of these `prefetch_related()` calls but that wasn't any help.

Below are the views for the job and job list, which is the full slow job query.

```
class JobApi(APIView):
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,
                       IsProjectManagerFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields  = ('id', 'practice_area', 'region', 'country', 'customer__entity', 'customer', 'platform',)


class JobList(JobApi, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,
                       IsProjectManagerFilterBackend,
                       MinMaxDateJobStatusFilterBackend,
                       JobClosedFilter,)
    serializer_class = serializers.JobListSerializer

    queryset = (models.Job.objects.all()
                # all part of Job model
                .prefetch_related('customer', 'project_manager')
                .prefetch_related('practice_area', 'region', 'country', 'platform')
                
                # each of these are 1:M with Job
                .prefetch_related('jobtask_set', 'billinginstruction_set')
                .prefetch_related('plmcost_set')
                
                # each of these are 1:M with JobTask
                .prefetch_related('jobtask_set__estimate_set')
                .prefetch_related('jobtask_set__cost_set', 'jobtask_set__hours_set'))
```

Comment: I'd say that this is too much for a single API request. Split this data into top-level info and details, use pagination, dont fetch all rows at once. At DB level use denormalization to speed up data retrieval. Ensure that there are all appropriate indicies.

Comment: Unfortunately, the view we are reporting requires aggregating all of these results. We may paginate some things, but we also need totals across the whole year. We are talking about simplifying that third level relationship (essentially if a cost has a job task, and a job task has a job, we could also add a job reference to the cost so that it isn't a nested lookup) but the general question still stands of possible ways to optimize a large query like this...

Comment: This does not sound like a regular work with Rest API. API should not be designed as ETL/dumping/reporting/data analysis subsystem. Your scenario could be implemented as a background task: someone requests the report (or all of the data for the report), API immediately returns task id, Celery or analogue does all the work in background, client app pings another API endpoint to check whether task has finished and eventually receives another url or json with the result.